# how can i navigate to another page with react?

Tags: html, reactjs, web

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {useState} from "react";
import Comparing from "./Comparing";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


function Criterion({ crit }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {crit}
        </div>
    )
}

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <div className={"navbar"}>
            <h1>AnalyticDecision</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

function App() {
  const [criteria, setCriteria] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const newCrit = event.target.newCrit.value

    setCriteria(curr => [newCrit, ...curr])

    event.target.reset()
  }

  return (
      <html>
          <body>
          <Navbar />
          <div className={"main"}>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <h1>Kriterleriniz</h1>
                  <input type={"text"} name={"newCrit"}/>
              </form>
              <div className={"criteria"}>
                  {criteria.map(crit => (
                      <div className={"criterion"}>
                          <Criterion crit={crit} />
                      </div>
                  ))}
              </div>
          </div>
          <Link to={"/Comparing"}>Next</Link>
          </body>
      </html>
  )
}


export default App;
```

i get "Right side of assignment cannot be destructured" error when i run this code with "Link" component.

i also tried to do this with router but it didn't work either. also i couldn't decide whether to use "router" or "browser router". what is the difference between them?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, regarding the error "Right side of assignment cannot be destructured", it's caused by incorrectly trying to destructure a value that is not an object or array. It's not directly related to the Link component or routing in React.

However, the code you have shared doesn't seem to have any such destructuring issue. There might be something in the other files or components that are causing this issue.

Now coming to your question about `BrowserRouter` and `Router`.Both `BrowserRouter` and `Router` are components provided by the `react-router-dom` package to manage the routing in your application.

1. **BrowserRouter**: This component uses the HTML5 history API (pushState,
   replaceState, and the popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with
   the URL. The BrowserRouter creates a browser history and is used for
   applications that have a dynamic server that can handle dynamic
   URLs.
2. **Router**: This is a low-level interface for all router components. It
   allows you to create your own history object of any type (browser,
   hash, memory). You can use it if you need more control over the
   behavior of the routes.

In most of the cases, developers use `BrowserRouter` for web applications because it takes care of creating the browser history for you. Router is used in more specific cases where you need to control the type of history that is being used.

Regarding your routing problem, your Link component must be enclosed within a `BrowserRouter` or else it will not work. So, the routing section of your code would look something like below:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Router>
  <Navbar />
  <div className={"main"}>
    ...
  </div>
  <Link to={"/Comparing"}>Next</Link>
</Router>
```

You need to ensure that the `Comparing` component is defined in your routes. You can use `Route` to define the component to render when the user navigates to a particular URL:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Router>
  <Navbar />
  <div className={"main"}>
    ...
  </div>
  <Link to={"/Comparing"}>Next</Link>

  <Route path="/Comparing" component={Comparing} />
</Router>
```